# Midori browser on Ubuntu 20 - Unable to create bookmark

Tags: ubuntu, gnome3

First time I use Midori browser, I tested on 2 different PC. When I want to save the current pasge as bookmark a popup opens (see image ) but there is no button to save the bookmark and typing Enter has no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like work on this feature is in progress.
There is open issue's  with same guestion on Midori's github :

https://github.com/midori-browser/core/issues/442
https://github.com/midori-browser/core/issues/208
https://github.com/midori-browser/core/issues/355

Looks like bookmarks feature is not implemented yet in Midori v.8:

https://github.com/midori-browser/core/issues/302

https://github.com/midori-browser/core/issues/79

Comment: Thanks , it's clearly issue #442, I did not think to have a look on gitub. (v7)